# Cucumber Capybara find checkbox by other than id, name, or label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to check a checkbox in my cucumber test, but I cannot figure out how to tell it to search by anything other than the id, name, or label.  I keep on getting this error:

```
cannot check field, no checkbox with id, name, or label 'xxxx' found
```

I have added an attribute of 'identifier' to each checkbox, with unique values, and would like to find the box by these terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean that you've added a new attribute named `identifier` to each checkbox?  If so then you may be able to find them using a CSS locator:

`find(:css, "[identifier='#{my_checkbox_identifier}']").set(true)`

(`set`-ing the checkbox to `true` checks it, use `false` to uncheck it.)

Comment: Yes, you're right - I meant I added that as an attribute.  However, when I try that code, I get this error: Unable to find css "[identifier='Check:NCO']" (Capybara::ElementNotFound).  The HTML generated is: <input id="xxx" type="checkbox" value="1" name="xxx" indentifier="my_checkbox_identifier">

Comment: I didn't get time to try that code out, perhaps you need to specify the element e.g. 'input[identifier=...'

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working for me ( Unable to find css "input[identifier=\"Check:NCO\"]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound) ).

Comment: I wonder where Check:NCO is coming from -are you passing that value in? is it the identifier you're trying to match against?

Comment: @Josh - could you post up a snippet of the HTML of one of your checkboxes, and the current step definition and scenario you're trying to use?  Ideally as an edit to your original question so the formatting is preserved.

Comment: I went to edit the post, and noticed a typo in my code.  I fixed it, and everything worked great.  So the two things you mentioned were exactly what I needed (along with me typing better...) Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Realizing this question is rather old, an answer may still be useful to someone, somewhere. I found the following to work:

`find(:xpath, "//input[@identifier='my_checkbox_identifier']").set(true)`